# Variational methods

Tags: variational-analysis

What happens if I use the free parameters in variational methods in a non-linear manner?

I have this question in front of me and I am not sure how to answer it.

Comment: Do you have a specific function?

Comment: I think one gets some sort of function that is a polynomial in the nonlinearity one has in mind. One then wants this to have a root at $s=0$. This seems like a really interesting idea indeed! Maybe new differential equations become accessible in this manner.